# Importing Excel sheets in R but getting extra data frame inserted

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, import

I tried to import an Excelfile with many sheets to R using this code (using `rio` package):

```
data_list <- import_list("x.xlsx")
```

it worked well but when I checked the number of sheets imported I discoverd an extra sheet by the name `RAW`

[image]

How can I import the sheets without getting this extra not needed data frame?

Comment: After importing all, do `data_list <- data_list[-1]`.

Comment: thank you :) and how can i bind all those sheets together?(without getting this extra RAw data frame ) becuse when i use this code :import_list("x.xlsx", setclass = "tbl", rbind = TRUE) it adds this RAw data frame again

Comment: Use `data.table::rbindlist` or `do.call(rbind, data_list)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you get the `RAW`, but I suggest using the `readxl`-package for reading excel-files to R.

```
library( readxl )

#get sheetnames of file
sheetnames <- readxl::excel_sheets( "./temp.xlsx" )
#loop over sheetname and read contenst, add to list
l <- lapply( sheetnames, function(x) readxl::read_excel( "./temp.xlsx", sheet = x ) )
#add sheetnames as names
names( l ) <- sheetnames
```

For binding together of `l`, I suggest `data.table::rbindlist()`. Make sure to set the `use.names`-, `fill`-, and `idcol`-argument to your needs.